# How to read Certification details in django Request Object?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, x509certificate, azure-store

We are trying integrate with Azure store. Azure store calls our API(built in django restframework) and along with request payload they send Certification details in request.

But, I cannot see the certification details (X509Certificate) in Django request Header, body, cookies or session.

Can any one help me on ways or location to read the X509Certificate2 certificate sent by Azure in Django request object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about X509 but a quick Google reveals [this library](https://github.com/novafloss/django-x509) which will probably help you.